# SharePoint 2010 "Tag Cloud Web Part"

Tags: tagging, managed-metadata, taxonomy

Can anyone give me an indication of how the Tag Cloud Web Part actually works, what fields it looks for to generate tags, etc?

I'm quite new to the managed metadata service, so I've fired it up, create a term set and some terms.

I want to add a taxonomy field to some lists (if there's a site column already there, that the Tag Cloud looks for, then perfect), so that the tag cloud web part can pick up on those taxonomy fields and generate the cloud (for a given site and it's subsites).

Can this be done with the Tag Cloud web part? Or am I gonna have to fire up Visual Studio and roll my own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a column in a list of type 'Managed Metadata'. This column allows you to set a specific Term Set to use in this column.

The TagCloud will not look at this field.

Unfortunately it only uses 'I like it' and the tags on the pages (social tagging).

As far as I know you have to build your own (or maybe someone did already).

Comment: Thanks Anita. Thought so as much, will be a fun project I'm sure ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you enable "Metadata Publishing" in your Libraries (under "Metadata and Keywords Settings"), your tags will not only be applied to your documents, but also be published to your user profile. This way the tags will appear in your Tag Cloud Web Part as well.